# Select onde ao filtrar um determinado produto, retornar outros produtos vinculados ao cupom

Tags: sql-select

Estou com uma dúvida sobre sql onde ao filtrar um código de produto retornar todos os outros produtos que foram vendidos no mesmo cupom.
A questão é onde o usuário quer filtrar durante um determinado período, tudo o que foi vendido no produto X e retornar as vendas com outros itens.

Exemplo:
Cupom : 123 / Produto(s): 1020 - SUCO / 1021 - REFRIGERANTE / 1237 - TRIDENT

Quando faço a consulta filtrando o produto EX: 1021, não traz os outros itens.

SELECT * FROM IT_CUPOM IT WHERE IT.produto containing '1021' AND IT.data between '01.08.2023' and '02.08.2023

Comment: Isso é SQL? nunca vi a palavra chave `containing` em um sql. Qual o o SGBD?

Comment: Firebird ou sql server, CONTAINS é um predicado usado na cláusula WHERE de uma instrução Transact-SQL SELECT para executar uma pesquisa de texto completo do SQL Server em colunas indexadas de texto completo que contêm tipos de dados baseados em caracteres.

Comment: pois é, a palavra-chave que eu perguntei não é `CONTAINS`. Mas contains eu conheço.

Comment: É a mesma coisa, similar ao Like no sql.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Fiz uma condição e após isso consegui trazer o resultado desejado!

```
 Condicao += "EXISTS(SELECT IT_C.cupom FROM SM_MV_PDV_IT_CUP IT_C WHERE IT_C.empresa   = CB.empresa "
                                                           + "  AND IT_C.data      = CB.data    "
                                                           + "  AND IT_C.pdv       = CB.pdv     "
                                                           + "  AND IT_C.cupom     = CB.cupom   "
                                                           + "  AND IT_C.produto   = " + this.pcProduto.TabelaRetornoChave + ")";
```

Answer (score -3):

Nas linguagens de SQL que estou acostumado talvez funcionasse assim, claro, precisa ver seu schema para ter certeza, isso é pelos dados que você passou!:

```
FROM IT_CUPOM IT
WHERE IT.cupom IN (
    SELECT cupom
    FROM IT_CUPOM
    WHERE produto = '1021' AND data BETWEEN '2023-08-01' AND '2023-08-02'
)
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).